# How to resolve a conflict between two jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery

Total jQuery novice, so go easy!

I have the following jQuery files in the `<head>`:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.mouse.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.sortable.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.tabs.min.js"></script>
<script src="./thesaurus/js/jquery.thesaurus.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the following doc ready calls:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#container').Thesaurus
({
   effect: 'fade',
   caseSensitive: true // Used when matching found terms against loaded ones
});
   var page2jQueryTabs1Opts =
   {
      event: 'click',
      collapsible: false
   };
   $("#page2jQueryTabs1").tabs(page2jQueryTabs1Opts);
});
</script>
```

The problem I have is that the Thesaurus works perfectly but the jQuery tabbed section does not.

I have been experimenting (for hours!) with `jQuery.noconflict()` but I suspect I have been wasting my time as I am only using one instance of jQuery? And my stabs at changing namespaces (I think that's what I have been trying!!) have failed miserably. For the record I am able to edit thesaurus.js and I have control over the first part of the doc ready but I can't change the sequence/order that the doc ready is produced - i.e. the `$('#container').Thesaurus` must appear first and I cannot edit the jQuery Tab part of the doc ready.

Rather than continue stabbing around in the dark with trial and error edits I ask the question ... what changes do I need to make to the markup...or the thesaurus.js file ([found here](http://demo.dsheiko.com/thesaurus/js/jquery.thesaurus.js)).

Time for some Aspirins now!

EDIT: [Test page](http://www.aditerum.co.uk/test/WWBTESTS/page2.html)

Comment: Please, try to create and example that shows your problem. With just this code snipet is hard to tell you something.

Comment: Ok. Your problem is that you can't change the active tab?

Comment: Correct. None of the tabs will change while the reference to .Thesaurus is in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to resolve the conflict using any of the `jQuery no.Conflict()` options here or from external research but I have resolved my problem simply by changing the line `$('#container').Thesaurus({` to `$('.someclass').Thesaurus({` so that instead of calling in a DIV it uses a CSS Class. Everything is now peachy :)

So many thanks to those that tried to help - as ever, always much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Sorry. I thought that firebug updated and executed the code locally, but it seems that it didn't do this... Please, try the code below and let me know if it worked...

I tried in Firebug and it worked. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var page2jQueryTabs1Opts = {
       event: 'click',
       collapsible: false
    };
    $("#page2jQueryTabs1").tabs(page2jQueryTabs1Opts);

    $.noConflict();

    $('#container').Thesaurus({
       effect: 'fade',
       caseSensitive: true // Used when matching found terms against loaded ones
    });

});
```

I just swaped the tabs and thesaurus declarations and put a $.noConflict() between them.

Comment: I have tried this and several variations. The jQuery Tabs work as expected but the Thesaurus jQuery doesn't. I have re-edited the page back to how it was (Thesaurus working) Tabs not - see dotted line under the word Oxidation and then hover.

Also I should point out that there will be circumstances when the doc ready statements could be very different. The Thesaurus could be first, second or third or ... in the list and I'll have no control over that. So I'll need to resolve the conflict for all possibilities.